# node.js and Handlebars: HTML compiled is escaped

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, template-engine, html-escape-characters

Im using handlebars in a node aplication, and I have trouble.

This is the template `index.html`

```
{{CONTENT}}
```

This is the code

```
var fs = require("fs");
var handlebars = require("handlebars");

var data = {
    CONTENT: "<b>Hello world!</b>"
};

var templateFile = fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf8');
var template = handlebars.compile( templateFile );
var html = template(data);
```

The problem is that the tags `<B>` are escaped to `&lt;B&gt;`

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com/) :

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash".

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{{body}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

with this context:

```
{
  title: "All about <p> Tags",
  body: "<p>This is a post about &lt;p&gt; tags</p>"
}
```

results in:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>All About &lt;p&gt; Tags</h1>
  <div class="body">
    <p>This is a post about &lt;p&gt; tags</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However from my point of view it may defeat the purpose of having a template separated than you're js file.

If you use [precompile](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) then use noEscape option:

```
handlebars.precompile(content, {noEscape: true})
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. This was just a test case. Its not not the purpose of what I'm trying to do ;)

Comment: Just saying `may` because sometimes you may not have an option, but when you do ...

Comment: Im just loading a template inside another template. Im using 2 HTML files.

Answer (score 29):

You'd want to use the 'triple stash' in your template:

```
{{{CONTENT}}}
```