# Phonegap ignoring basic Html tags

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, handlebars.js

I am getting data inside HTML tags from my service like this-

```
<b><i>Hello</i><b> 
<h2>World</h2>
```

I want my application to show that data after interpreting the tags -

> *Hello*
>
> ### World

but it is showing as it is with tags. I am using Handlebar.js to display data.

Comment: The html tags are being escaped. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807799/node-js-and-handlebars-html-compiled-is-escaped  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple stash

{{{content}}}