# HTML encode and decode in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am working on a Backbone.js app and sending request to my API for JSON data to be show on the front end with Backbone Template.

The returned JSON has some HTML entities within the JSON array, and the HTML is getting printed as text.

Below is my template code:

```
{{#each this}}
<li>
    <a >&nbsp;</a>
    <section class="ip">
        <p><% {{title}} %></p>
        <h3>
            <time class="timeago" datetime="{{pubDate}}"></time>
            {{type}}
        </h3>
    </section>
</li>
{{/each}}

{{#unless this}}
<p>Der er pt ingen sociale opdateringer om denne artist</p>
{{/unless}}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what templating engine you're using, but the syntax looks like Handlebars for the most part, so that's what I'm going to assume.

In order to escape HTML entities in Handlebars, you need to use {{{triple mustaches}}}

For example, you have JSON:

```
{
    text: "<p>My paragraph</p>"
}
```

Your template might look like this:

```
<div>
    {{{text}}}
</div>
```

And your output:

```
<div>
    <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Isnt it `{{text}}` - 2 brackets instead of 3?

Comment: @SHT I think if you want the HTML contained within the text property to be rendered as HTML, you need to use triple mustaches `{{{text}}}`. Using two brackets will escape the HTML and produce output along the lines of `"&lt;p&gt;My paragraph&gt;/p&lt;"` Unless I'm missing something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807799/node-js-and-handlebars-html-compiled-is-escaped

Comment: You are absolutely right! Just tried it out and it works perfectly!

Comment: @SHT Ah, that's a relief :)