# Html is not showing correctly in Node Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I insert data using summernote text editor. When i render this in my page than it is showing like `&lt;p&gt;somthing&lt;/p&gt;`. And i want this as plain text.

**JS Code**

```
exports.Blog = function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.Id != null) {
        connection.init();
        connection.query("select * from blog_posts where user_id=? order by date_created desc", [req.session.Id], function (reqest, row, fields) {
            res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
            res.render('Blog', { rows: row });
        });
    }
    else {
        res.render('login');
    }
};
```

**ejs code**

```
<%var result=rows%>
<%
  for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
  {
%>
  <div class="well">
    <div id="desc-<%=result[i].Id%>"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () { 
          var desc='<%=result[i].description%>';
          console.log(desc);
          $('#desc-<%=result[i].Id%>').html(desc);
       });
    </script>
  </div>
<%
 }
%>
```

Comment: did you see the console.log(JSON.stringify(row)); ,, is there data or not?

Comment: When i use console.log(JSON.stringify(desc)); than result is remains same @MuhammadAli

Comment: I'm not node.js guy, but last answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807799/node-js-and-handlebars-html-compiled-is-escaped) question might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%var result=rows%>
<%
  for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
  {
%>
  <div class="well">
    <div id="desc-<%-result[i].Id%>"><%-result[i].description%></div>

  </div>
<%
 }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you generating script to insert html you can directly put description into div.

```
<%var result=rows%>
<%
  for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
  {
%>
  <div class="well">
    <div id="desc-<%-result[i].Id%>"><%=result[i].description%></div>

  </div>
<%
 }
%>
```